# how to get current debugging process's info in __lldb_init_module?

Tags: python, debugging, lldb

the lldb extension script's entrypoint is:

```py
def __lldb_init_module(debugger, internal_dict):
```

however, when I access `debugger.target`, it's `No Value`.

lots of tutorial shows how to use `SBDebugger.CreateTarget` to create new target and process, but now I'm debugging from IDE's debug workflow, I don't think I should create target myself, I just want to get(or wait for) the current debugging process(launched by IDE) and target, then invoke some commands as `pro hand -p true -s false SIGPWR`.

so the problem is how could I access the `current target` in the none-standalone-launch mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In command-line lldb there are two stages of reading in init files.

The ~/.lldbinit is read in the first phase, before any targets get made.  That way commands in it can condition the construction of the targets.  So modules sourced there won't see any targets.

Then if there is a .lldbinit in the CWD, that will get sourced after any targets specified on the command line.  So that will see the target.

The equivalent in Xcode (if you are using a fairly recent Xcode) is the lldbinit you can specify in the run scheme's options tab.

The other way to do this is to set an auto-continue breakpoint on main, and source your .lldbinit at that point.  Note, if you want to use `process handle` there has to be a running process, so you need to do that in a breakpoint somewhere...